# Sending email in telnet with bash script, unexpected token 'newline' with MAIL FROM:<>

Tags: bash, shell, email, telnet

I am trying to send an email using telnet in a bash script, I was able to do this without the bash script but wanted to make it more user friendly. I thought the newline was important for telnet to process information, but it's telling me it's producing an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter your email'
read email

echo 'Enter your password'
read password

echo 'Enter who you want to send an email to'
read recipient

echo 'Enter your subject'
read subject

echo 'Enter your message'
read message

newPassword=$(echo -ne $password | base64)
newEmail=$(echo -ne $email | base64)

(
telnet -z ssl smtp.gmail.com 465
echo 'Sleeping: about to run HELO'
sleep 2
HELO hellogoogle
echo 'Sleeping: about to run AUTH'
sleep 2
AUTH LOGIN
echo 'Sleeping: about to enter email'
sleep 2
newEmail
echo 'Sleeping: about to enter password'
sleep 2
newPassword
echo 'Sleeping: about to run FROM'
sleep 2
MAIL FROM:<email>
echo 'Sleeping: about to run TO'
sleep 2
RCPT TO:<recipient>
echo 'Sleeping: about to run DATA'
sleep 2
DATA
echo 'Sleeping: about to enter subject'
sleep 2
Subject: subject
echo 'Sleeping: about to enter message'
sleep 2
message
.
) | telnet
```

[image: This is the error I am getting]

I tried to do this without the parenthesis and it still did not work. Since it takes some time for telnet to open up I added sleep in between each command, along with an output letting me know what is happening.

I am trying to send an email to myself using telnet with a bash script.

Comment: The error message does not come from `telnet`.  You are trying to execute the command `MAIL FROM:<email>`, which means that you run a command named `MAIL` with standard input redirected from file `email`. The standard output redirection `>` is lacking a filename, and this yields the syntax error. You would get the same syntax error from the command line, if you type the command `x>`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck using a heredoc which can contain variables. Here's a basic example of sending a command to webserver using netcat:

```bash
file='index.html'

cat <<EOT | nc www.example.com 80
GET /$file HTTP/1.0

EOT
```

I don't have telnet which is why I'm using netcat. There's a new version that supports ssl. The heredoc should also work with telnet.